# Magento 2.3.1 How to display source or stock name on product page ? MSI Multii Source Inventory

Tags: magento2.3, stock, code, name, source

How to display source or stock name and code on the product page? Where is information about a current stock or source name? Can I use the code from Sourceitem.php on the Product page?

```
     public function getSourceCode(): ?string
 {
     return $this->getData(self::SOURCE_CODE);
 }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GetSourceItemBySku` to get all `SourceItem` from product's sku. Then you can foreach the array and `getSourceCode()` from SourceItem.

Please check this path: `/vendor/magento/module-inventory/Model/SourceItem/Command/GetSourceItemsBySku.php`

After defined and declared `GetSourceItemsBySkuInterface`, just use it in your function.

> $availableSourcesForProduct = $this->sourceItemsBySku->execute($sku);

Refer this file to know how to use it, `/vendor/magento/module-inventory-grouped-product-admin-ui/Plugin/Catalog/Model/Product/Link/ProcessSourceItemsAfterSaveAssociatedLinks.php`. Check function `processSourceItemsForSku`

Good luck!!!